# Wine Windows Program Loader - out of memory

Tags: wine, memory-usage

I'm running an old game (WoW 1.12) using Wine. On the particular server I'm playing on the crowding of people can make the game chew up memory fast. I frequently get a crash where the error is "out of memory". How can I allocate more memory for a particular program run by the loader?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "allocate more memory for a particular program", that's not how Linux works.

You can either purchase and add more RAM to the server, OR use swap. Read `man mkswap` and `man swapon`.

Comment: I assume you mean the game server. If you mean some other server then I don't understand. The game server is not giving me the error, it's the wine program loader. I want the program loader to be allowed to utilise more of my system RAM (I have 16GB). Sorry if my phrasing was not clear.